# Lost 24 pin to 24 pin+2 pin(mini) splitter that came PC case, cannot use touch panel. What to do?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, cable, case

I'll preface this by saying that I don't know much about cables/electricity. I got this limited edition case called the [InWin Tou](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/elite-atx-case-inwin-tou-silverstone-ft04,3812-5.html) back in 2014 and never got the actual parts to build a PC with it until now... however, I've lost all the accessories that came with the case, including a very important 24-pin adapter that appears to split 24 pin into 24 pin + mini 2-pin. The 2-pin cable goes into a touch panel which controls the light inside the case (the whole gimmick of the case is that it turns transparent with light) and without it the touch panel doesn't appear to work. The images below show 1) a schematic of where the cable goes, 2) a description of the cable, 3) an image of what the cable looks like.

1. [image: Schematic]
2. [image: Cable Description]
3. [image: Cable photo]

Is there any way I could source a similar cable? or are there any other alternatives to using the same cable, like somehow finding a mini 2-pin cable that connects to my PSU? Would I risk frying the panel if I try using a different cable than the one that came with the case? (this would be pretty bad as its a very rare case and could not be replaced).

Would definitely appreciate any help.

Comment: The cable *looks* like a common 24-to-24 pin ATX extension cable with an attached power/GND cable + connector for the touch panel. If you find out what supply the touch panel needs (probably 3.3 or 5.0V) and find the right connector for the touch display (unclear from the pictures), it should be doable to make your own cable.

Comment: From the link you provided the ATX extension cable could be non-standard (but I can’t tell for sure). The connector to the touch panel is almost certainly a 2-pin female JST connector.